# Attach console to .Net Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, worker-service

I currently have several .Net windows services running on my server. Is there a way to attach a console app to the service to get all of the ILogger data? I have had issues where the service runs perfectly as a console app/worker service but as soon as I run it as a windows service, it just sits there and does nothing.

I did find an article about attaching the VS debugger to the process, but this will not work with our network security.

I am open to any other suggestions as well.

Comment: Well, can't you configure your logging to log to a file? Then you can simply tail it or analyse the files ...

Comment: The answer is simply "**no**". A Windows Service cannot have a console attached. If it's just for logging, you have plenty of better options. Fildor mentioned file logging. You can also log to -- wait for it -- the Windows Event Log.

Comment: If you need to present a user interface (console or GUI), you need to create a separate process that runs in the user's profile context and communicates with the service. That's how lots of commercial applications provide background services (e.g. printing, anti-virus) as well as a user interface to it.

Comment: @Fildor I thought about this. My concern is how the performance would be affected by the open/write/close of a file.

Comment: @madreflection I would like to see how other implement this concept of connecting to the service.

Comment: _"My concern is how the performance would be affected by the open/write/close of a file"_ - is it affected by the errors?

Comment: @GuyCothal: Named pipes, sockets (raw, self-hosted web API, or any number of other application protocols, sky's the limit), global events/semaphores... it's a broad topic, and there are many ways to implement IPC. You'd have to do some research.

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer is no, but as @Fildor mentioned, you would set up a log sink of some sort. The file logger is just an example, but you can also have the logs send emails, post to some cloud logging service such as splunk or cloudwatch, etc.

One issue you may run into is that you need to capture an error prior to ILogger being available and properly configured for you. Here is a guide I followed for capturing startup errors using NLog: https://alistairevans.co.uk/2019/10/04/asp-net-core-3-0-logging-in-the-startup-class-with-nlog/

Startup classes are no longer necessary in the latest .NET version, so I modified their example to be code you would have in Program.cs:

```
// NLog: setup the nlog config first
NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

try
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        // Use NLog to provide ILogger instances.
        .UseNLog()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = nlogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger(typeof(Program).FullName);
}
```

}

Here's the list of available log sinks you can configure in that nlog configuration file: https://nlog-project.org/config/

This same thing can be accomplished with other log providers you may already be using such as Serilog, Log4Net, etc.